# Yahrzeit candle. Is the observance to light the candle or that it should be alight?

Tags: candle-lighting, yahrtzeit

Two people have yahrzeits for their relatives on two successive days. They agree to light a 2-day candle. Can the day-2 person rely on that candle for his observance or should he extinguish it and relight it?

Comment: on this site https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/3034297/jewish/Why-Do-We-Light-a-Yahrtzeit-Memorial-Candle.htm the few sources references have to do with a light being lit, not the lighting itself.

Comment: interesting question. From the title, I was wondering if you were asking about כבתה אין זקוק לה lol :)